# Regex to capture URI that ends with UUID but not anything else

Tags: regex

I want to match a URI (includes a path and a UUID) that looks like this via a javascript regex:

```
/account/0006a8a6-b301-4168-b7de-964773a1ec66
```

The regex I have come closest to is this:

```
^\/([a-zA-Z0-9_\.~-]+)\/([a-f0-9]{8}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{12})
```

Works fine for capturing the above - I get a match and it captures as two groups.

However, if I enter this as the URI:

```
/account/0006a8a6-b301-4168-b7de-964773a1ec66DSSSSSS
```

The regex still matches and captures the two groups, and the second match is still just the UUID, but I need it to actually fail the match and not capture anything due to the DSSSSS appended at the end.  How can I change around my regex to accomplish this?

Comment: I hope you plan on escaping the forward slash you have in the middle of your expression "/".

Comment: Isn't \/ escaping it?  My captures work perfectly.  I get the above as capture 1: account and capture 2: 0006a8a6-b301-4168-b7de-964773a1ec66.  Should I be doing something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to add the end of line [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `$`

```
^\/([a-zA-Z0-9_\.~-]+)\/([a-f0-9]{8}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{12})$
```

Answer (score 2):

I see youre using the start of line anchor (^). Try using the end line anchor ($).

```
^/([a-zA-Z0-9_.~-]+)/([a-f0-9]{8}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{12})$
```